# Stopping Further Execution until UIScrollView ends animating

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, animation, uiscrollview

I have following scenario,

I have uiScrollView with its contentOffset at starting equal to (0.0,0.0)

now i have set new scrollView contentOffset with animation as

```
[myScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(100.0,0.0) animated:YES];
```

now on nextLine i am printing contentOffset's value

```
NSLog(@"ContentOffset:%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(myScrollView.contentOffset));
```

now here, it is printing the older value of contentOffset. If i set value without doing animation then it is giving me new ContentOffset.

What should i do so that, it will give me new value of contentOffset with animation too

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to setup a delegate for the `UIScrollView` and listen for the delegate method `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:`.  Then get the scroll position inside that method and call the next bit of code that you need to run once that value is found.

Comment: I am setting ContentOffset manually, in this case,any of delegate method is never going to be called, Delegate methods are only getting called when touches are done. Here, I am setting content offset by code. Read the question properly and then answer

Comment: @MehulThakkar I did read the question properly and you are setting the contentOffset property with animation.  That will still call every delegate method possible on the way to that final content offset.  Meaning you will get `scrollViewDidScroll` a whole bunch of times and then a `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:` call when it is complete.  Read the documentation properly and get your answer.

Comment: I haven't read the documentation, but the main problem with me is that  on next line of setting content offset i am not getting its new value, what if i want to get right value at that point, i dont want to move that code in delegate methods(if i do that then many of other variables are needed to change scope and makes lots of problem, os is there atleast any way(may be using block) so that i can use that at that same point)

Comment: If you are setting the offset via code (some variable or hard coded) then you know exactly where it is going to end, you don't have to wait for it.  Just use your variable or hard coded value and move on.  if I say `x = 6` and I want the value of `x` right after that setting I can either use `x` or `6` since I know both are the same at that point.